# Why can't I access application.properties values outside of my @SpringBootApplication-annotated main file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a custom defined key-value pair in my Spring Boot `application.properties` file:

```
jwt.secret=secretkey
```

I've created a configuration class for this property in the same directory as the runner class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jwt")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class JwtProperties {

    /**
     * Secret key used to sign JSON Web Tokens
     */
    private String secret = "";

    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }

    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }
}
```

As expected, I can access this value in my main Spring runner class, `ServerApplication.java` using the `@Value` annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JwtProperties.class)
public class ServerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    String test;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // correctly prints "test is: secretkey"
        System.out.println("test is " + test);
    }
}
```

I have a class `/security/JwtClient.java` where I'd like to be able to use this `jwt.secret` property, **but I can't get the `@Value` annotation to work** (it always results in a `null` String):

```
@Component
public class JwtClient {

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secretKey;

    public String buildJWT(Customer customer) {
        // incorrectly prints "secret key: null"
        System.out.println("secret key: " + secretKey);

        // attempts to build JSON Web Token here but secret key is missing
    }

}
```

I've read many StackOverflow questions on this topic, but almost all of them seem to assume that the `@Value` annotation will work properly on a `@Component`-annotated class.  What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you creating the `JwtClient`? The value injection will only happen if Spring creates it - you can't call the constructor yourself.

Comment: Remove `JwtProperties` class and `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation and the @Value will get injected.

Comment: @PMah Thank you for asking this question, I wasn't even thinking about how `JwtClient` was being used.  I was creating it with a default constructor `new JwtClient()` in a controller class.  I tried injecting it as a dependency via `@Autowired` and now it is able to obtain the correct value from `application.properties`.  Thanks so much for bringing this to my attention, this resolves the issue.